# Pull NSDates from plist and only display today's and tomorrow's events in tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In a plist I have several dictionaries (events, eg. soccer matches) in an array that looks like this:

```
<dict>
    <key>date</key>
    <date>2011-11-24T00:00:00Z</date>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>Amsterdam - Roosendaal</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>date</key>
    <date>2012-06-25T00:00:00Z</date>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>Rotterdam - Utrecht</string>
</dict>
```

And I have a tableview in which I have sections named 'Today' and 'Tomorrow'. Now whenever an event is happening today, I would like to see it in the section 'Today', and when the event is planned for tomorrow, in 'Tomorrow'.

EDIT: I now have this code:

```
self.Array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"matches" ofType:@"plist"]];

for (int i=0; i<[Array count]; i++) {
        NSDate *datum = [[Array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"datum"];
        NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:       (NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSDate *today = [cal dateFromComponents:components];
        components = [cal components:(NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:datum];
        NSDate *otherDate = [cal dateFromComponents:components];

        if([today isEqualToDate:otherDate]) {

        //do stuff

        NSLog(@"%i, %@", i, otherDate);
        NSLog(@"Match is today");

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Match is not today");
    }
```

From NSLog it seems that it makes the comparison in a right way. I now however want to display those dictionaries that have today's date together in a section. I guess I therefore have to create an array of them (maybe by adding things in the '//do stuff' area, such as  addObject?) Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also look into NSCalendar and NSDateComponents as well.  You can use them to get the day (or day+month+year, or absolute day in an era) as an integer that the date fall on. That way you can compare two times as being on the same day, along the boundaries of a calendar day.  (It will take into account daylight savings and other oddities for you as well).

You can also use them to convert the current date ([NSDate date]) to the date for the start of this day.  Examples are in the apple doc for the classes.

[edit] After you have that part (sounds like you do) then you say you want to display it in a table with sections.  Basically after the test for same/day want to set up a 2 dimensional array (more specifically, An NSArray with 2 objects which are themselves NSMutableArrays).  One of the NSMutableArrays you add the today objects to, the other you add the tomorrow objects to.

Once you have that, you can fill in the tableview delegate and datasource methods to populate the table.  (For example, the number of sections will be the count of your outer array, and each cell's index path will correspond to the outer array (section) and the inner mutable array (row).) Use the TableView programming guide for more details.

Comment: i've edited the post with the code I'm struggling with now. You might have some thoughts on it. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: i added more to the posted answer.  Also, looking at your code, it would be more efficient to move as much of your setup of your calendar and for today's date to before your for loop, instead of inside like you have it now.  Some date operations can be expensive.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds clear. Will look in the documentation for those arrays, as I lack the knowledge. Is looking at addObject a good place to start? Thanks again, great help.

Comment: addObject is indeed what you'll need to add objects to the inner arrays.  Adding the two inner arrays into the outer array can be accomplished when you create the outer array by calling NSArray's method 'arrayWithObjects'.  Once again if you can get the hang of everything in the Tableview Programming Guide, you'll be in good shape.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First, don't do the comparison with strings, keep the data in it's [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) form.

Then try

```
 if ( [myDate timeIntervalSinceDate:dateOfEvent] < 86400 ) { // less than a day apart.
 }
```

(Using [myDate isEqualToDate:dateOfEvent] does an EXACT comparison (to the second), so don't use that).

You will have to fine-tune this to determine what a "day" actually is, you'll need to find the day boundaries, but that shouldn't be too tough.

When you want to present a date to the user, use [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDateFormatter).

You can also convert these to just dates (no timestamp) using NSDateFormatter, and then compare those strings, so you'd be comparing 2011/16/11 to 2011/15/11 for example.
Like so:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDate *tomorrow = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval:86400];
NSString *eventDateString = @"2011-11-24T00:00:00Z";    // get your date string from the array
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"]; // this matches your dictionary's format

NSDate *eventDate = [df dateFromString:eventDateString];

// now you have 3 dates.  convert them to timeless strings using another date formatter.
NSDateFormatter *timeless = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeless setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[timeless setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSString *todayString    = [timeless stringFromDate:today];
NSString *tomorrowString = [timeless stringFromDate:tomorrow];
eventDateString          = [timeless stringFromDate:eventDate];
if ( [todayString isEqualToString:eventDateString ] ) {
    NSLog(@" today %@  == event: %@", todayString, eventDateString);
} else if ( [tomorrowString isEqualToString:eventDateString] ) {
    NSLog(@" tomorrow %@  == event: %@", tomorrowString, eventDateString);
}
[df release];
[timeless release];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It makes sense to me and will try to implement soon. However, I'm not planning on displaying the actual date, but rather only the 'title' in the right section. I might be demanding to much from you, but any thoughts on what code to include within the 'if' statement to achieve that, or a direction to continue my journey?

Comment: I now use `[today isEqualToDate:eventDate]` and this seems to work. However, I have still no clue how, if indeed equal, the title of the event can be displayed to the user in the 'Today'-section in tableview.

Comment: How to display the title is an entirely different question, and you should read up on UITableViewCell and cellForRowAtIndexPath:, as well as look at some of the sample projects that show tables.